# Warning: '%s' directive writing up to 2047 bytes into a region of size 56 [-Wformat-overflow=]

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I have a overflow warning but i dont understand what is wrong.I have gcc10.

This is entire code block.

Also  i'm try char name 2048 or 1024 or 512 or 256 also 64 - 128 getting same warn every time, i'm search almost every stackflow post but nothing get anything...What is the thing i cant see ?

```
struct stat sb;
int num1, num2;
char buf[32];
char system_cmd[64];
struct tm new_tm;

if (stat(filename, &sb) == -1)
{
    perror ("log_file_delete_old: stat");
    return;
}

if (!S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
{
    return;
}

new_tm = *tm_calc (NULL, -log_keep_days);
sprintf (buf, "%04d%02d%02d", new_tm.tm_year + 1900, new_tm.tm_mon + 1, new_tm.tm_mday);
num1 = atoi(buf);

struct dirent** namelist;
int n;

n = scandir (filename, &namelist, 0, alphasort);

if (n < 0)
{
    perror ("scandir");
}
else
{
    char name[MAXNAMLEN + 1];

    while (n-- > 0)
    {
        strncpy (name, namelist[n]->d_name, 255);
        name[255] = '\0';

        free (namelist[n]);

        if (*name == '.')
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isdigit (*name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        num2 = atoi (name);

        if (num2 <= num1)
        {
            sprintf (system_cmd, "rm -rf %s/%s", filename, name);
            system (system_cmd);

            sys_log (0, "%s: SYSTEM_CMD: %s", __FUNCTION__, system_cmd);
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: SYSTEM_CMD: %s %s:%d %s:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, system_cmd, buf, num1, name, num2);
        }
    }
}

    free (namelist);
```

Comment: `system_cmd` is only 64 bytes large. `filename` and `name` could be longer.

Comment: Can you remove all the irrelevant code please. You're expected to post a [mcve] (emphasis on _minimal_), which is sufficient to reproduce the error (warning).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Igor, the problem is system_cmd.I'm edit system_cmd 512 and name 128 thats solve the warning.